# downloading large files through php force header code not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is the form which im using for user to click on this download button.

```
<form action="verify.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<input name="filename" type="hidden" value="media.mp4">
<input name="filesize" type="hidden" value="2.0GB"><p></p>
<div align="center">
<input alt="Download" src="Download-Button.png" type="image" width="225"></div>
</form>
```

Inside verify.php im using this

```
<?php $file = $_POST["filename"]; ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=download.php?file=<?php echo $file; ?>">
    <title>Verify Page</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

And force header is placed in download.php

```
<?php
$file = 'uploads/' . $_GET['file'];

if( !file_exists($file) ) die("File not found");

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file));
header('Content-type: video/mp4');

readfile($file);
?>
```

but when it comes to large files like above 1GB or 2GB it sometimes generate 500 internal error or even sometimes files are less then 500MB or above still it sometimes generate that error below:

**This site can’t be reached**

> The webpage at
>   http://example.com/download.php?file=media.mp4
>   might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new
>   web address. ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

I've increased memory limits from php.ini and Apache as well. even try to use .htaccess to allocate memory but nothing is working! please guide me what should i do? or a solution for this?

Comment: According to the manual: `readfile() will not present any memory issues, even when sending large files, on its own. If you encounter an out of memory error ensure that output buffering is off with ob_get_level(). `

Comment: have you tried `set_time_limit(0);` ? you should look at your PHP error logs and not depend on your browser output.

Comment: @cmorrissey where should i use set_time_limit(0); ?

Comment: @jeroen  it says output_buffering = 4096 and by default in comments it say off.

Comment: @Jayanta Please check this error!